Linewidth from correlation functions
I work on cavity modes interacting with matter inside the cavity and I want to determine the linewidth of the light. I do not have excess to the state of the system directly but in a steady state, I can compute a variety of photon correlators, namely
$
\langle a (t)\rangle \qquad \langle a^\dagger (t') a(t) \rangle_c \qquad \langle a(t) a^\dagger (t')  \rangle_c \qquad \langle a (t') a(t) \rangle_c \qquad \langle a (t) a(t') \rangle_c
$
where the subscribed c means connected.
The system has two distinct regimes.
In the "normal" phase all anomalous correlators are zero, so $\langle a (t)\rangle=0$ and  $\langle a (t) a(t') \rangle_c=0 $.
In a steady state, I can compute the linewidth by Fourier transforming the spectral function $\langle [a(t),a^\dagger(t') ]\rangle_c$ wrt. to relative time. If the concept of linewidth is applicable, the spectra will show a Lorentzian shape, and I can fit the width.
In the coherent phase also the other correlators are finite. The coherent field is then of the form $\langle a (t)\rangle = e^{-i E t} \varphi$, where $\varphi$ is some complex number and $E$ the energy of the light. My question here is how to determine the spectral width of the coherent light. At first glance, it seems that it is zero since its time evolution is just a plane wave, but the correlators $\langle a (t) a(t') \rangle_c$ also encode fluctuations, which should lead to noise.
